# jQuery Validate plugin, one out of two fields is required

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form with 2 fields; mobile no. and telephone no.

at least 1 of the fields has to be filled in, but both can also be filled.

I need jquery validate to throw an error if none of them are filled only.

I have achieved this with:

```
rules: {
            mobile:{
                required: {
                    depends: function(element) {
                        return $("#regTelephone").val() === '';
                    }
                }
            },
            telephone:{
                required: {
                    depends: function(element) {
                        return $("#regMobile").val() === '';
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

however, if only one field is empty, this field still gets the 'valid' class, which I don't want as my valid css has a green border (so the empty field still gets a green border)

so: how do I get the field which is empty (providing the other has a value) to not get the valid class and therefore the green border?

Comment: You could put an if statement after it is validated to remove the valid class if the `.val` is null

Comment: @Zeaklous, FYI, the plugin already has a rule/method for this situation called `require_from_group`.

Answer (score 15):

Using [the optional `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js), there is a method called `require_from_group` that does exactly what you request.  (You must use *at least* version 1.11.1 of the plugin in order to avoid a past bug.)

```
rules: {
    mobile:{
        require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup']
    },
    telephone:{
        require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup']
    }
},
....
```

The `1` parameter is how many from the group are required.  In the HTML markup, the fields in your group must contain a `class` matching the `class` specified in your second parameter.

```
<input type="text" class="mygroup" name="mobile" />
<input type="text" class="mygroup" name="telephone" />
```

**Working DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/NfcxX/

My demo also shows the `groups` option which combines the multiple error messages into one.

Comment: I've encountered a problem with this. It seems to prevent other fields from being validated. I've added an initial 'title' field and the validation gets ignore: http://jsfiddle.net/NfcxX/19/

Comment: @Andy,  there is some talk at GitHub about this bug being fixed in the latest beta version not yet released.

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="text" name="mobile" id="regMobile">
<input type="text" name="telephone" id="regTelephone">

rules: {
            mobile:{
                required: {
                    depends: function(element) {
                        return $("#regTelephone").val() == ''
                    }
                }
            },
            telephone:{
                required: {
                    depends: function(element) {
                        return $("#regMobile").val() == ''
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: If it was this simple, we wouldn't need the `require_from_group` method.