# How to implement "or" condition in Jquery validation rules

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am currently using jquery validation plugin to validate my form, here i want to validate *Landline number*  and *mobile number* .User want to enter any one.So I Want to use **Or** condition in jquery validation rules.

```
rules{ 'landline':{ required:true }, 'mobile':{ required:true } }
```

How to make any one field mandatory.

Comment: Maybe it will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18315072/jquery-validate-plugin-one-out-of-two-fields-is-required

Comment: Just use the method specifically created for this situation called `require_from_group`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
landline: {
    required: function(element) {
        if ($("#m_no").val().length > 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    },
    number: true
},
mobile: {
    required: function(element) {
        if ($("#land_no").val().length > 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    },
    number: true
}
```

Comment: Whether I want to include "addtional-method.js"  for this code??

Comment: @user1665624 no just use with normal js file it will work fine

Comment: Your code in a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/46Bx9/  ~ There is no reason for this when there is already a method called `require_from_group` designed specifically for this situation.  Besides, there are issues with your code that leaves error messages in place until form validation is triggered again.

Answer (score 9):

If you want the error messages to properly toggle and keep your code looking concise, just use the method that was created specifically for this situation.  The rule/method is called [`require_from_group`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method/) and included in [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js).

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            landline: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.phone'],
                number: true
            },
            mobile: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.phone'],
                number: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/t45dc/**

And to optionally combine both error messages into one, use the `groups` option...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            landline: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.phone'],
                number: true
            },
            mobile: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.phone'],
                number: true
            }
        },
        groups: {
            phones: 'landline mobile'
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/t45dc/1/**

Comment: @sridharr This is the answer I was looking for and it appears to be the solution for OP as well.  It should be marked correct.  I would add the documentation as well. http://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include `additional-methods.js`.

You need to extract required part from validaor.js and additional-methods.js and define like this one

Add one method `elementValue`  to validator prototype :

```
$.validator.prototype.elementValue = function( element ) {
            var $element = $( element ),
                type = element.type,
                val, idx;

            if ( type === "radio" || type === "checkbox" ) {
                return this.findByName( element.name ).filter( ":checked" ).val();
            } else if ( type === "number" && typeof element.validity !== "undefined" ) {
                return element.validity.badInput ? "NaN" : $element.val();
            }

            if ( element.hasAttribute( "contenteditable" ) ) {
                val = $element.text();
            } else {
                val = $element.val();
            }

            if ( type === "file" ) {

                // Modern browser (chrome & safari)
                if ( val.substr( 0, 12 ) === "C:\\fakepath\\" ) {
                    return val.substr( 12 );
                }

                // Legacy browsers
                // Unix-based path
                idx = val.lastIndexOf( "/" );
                if ( idx >= 0 ) {
                    return val.substr( idx + 1 );
                }

                // Windows-based path
                idx = val.lastIndexOf( "\\" );
                if ( idx >= 0 ) {
                    return val.substr( idx + 1 );
                }

                // Just the file name
                return val;
            }

            if ( typeof val === "string" ) {
                return val.replace( /\r/g, "" );
            }
            return val;
        }
```

And define new rule :

```
$.validator.addMethod("require_from_group", function(value, element, options) {
        var $fields = $(options[1], element.form),
            $fieldsFirst = $fields.eq(0),
            validator = $fieldsFirst.data("valid_req_grp") ? $fieldsFirst.data("valid_req_grp") : $.extend({}, this),
            isValid = $fields.filter(function() {
                return validator.elementValue(this);
            }).length >= options[0];

        // Store the cloned validator for future validation
        $fieldsFirst.data("valid_req_grp", validator);

        // If element isn't being validated, run each require_from_group field's validation rules
        if (!$(element).data("being_validated")) {
            $fields.data("being_validated", true);
            $fields.each(function() {
                validator.element(this);
            });
            $fields.data("being_validated", false);
        }
        return isValid;
    }, $.validator.format("Please select at least {0} Energy or Water fields."));
```

And new field rule synatx :

```
energyCategory: {
                  require_from_group: [1,'.select-drop-down']
                },
waterCategory: {
                require_from_group: [1,'.select-drop-down']
               }
```

This will work with old jquery validation plugin version 1.9 also without need to upgrade to new one.