# jQuery Validate for address fields where at least one of three is required

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Been getting my "feet wet" with jQuery Validate, and have the basics working as needed. There's one rather prickly situation, however, that I can't seem to grasp. I need to require a complete physical address to be entered, and I cannot simply do so by requiring all the constituent fields (street, city, etc.). The way the constituent fields are set-up is as follows:

```
    StreetLine1
    StreetLine2
    POBox
    City
    State
    Zip
```

Street 1, Street 2, and PO Box form a group in that at least one of those is required, along with the remaining 3 fields, i.e.:

```
    {StreetLine1 || StreetLine2 || POBox} &&
    City &&
    State &&
    Zip
```

Can't seem to find a simple way to do that... The group feature within the validate definition doesn't seem to do what I need it to do.

Comment: The `groups` option has nothing to do with this... it might be needed but it's just for grouping three messages together into one.  First, you need to show us the relevant HTML and JavaScript.  Second, there is a rule/method for this.  I'll either post an answer or close this one with a link to the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks -- I could not find any similar cases for some reason, but the link to the duplicate looks like it's probably what I want. Nothing marked as an accepted answer in it, but I can probably get what I need from what's presented there...

Comment: See this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18317702/594235