# JQuery Validate with different conditions

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have three fields.  The validation should be like so

`fieldOne` - Required if **fieldTwo** not present

`fieldTwo` - Required if **fieldOne** not present

`fieldThree` - **Always required**

So `fieldOne` and `fieldTwo` depend on each other.  Either one or the other can be provided, or they both can be provide.  Whatever happens though, `fieldThree` is always required.

So far I have the following

```
var validator = $("#my_form").validate({
    groups: {
        datagroup: "fieldOne fieldTwo"
    },
    rules: {
        fieldOne: {
            require_from_group: [1, '.datagroup'],
            email: true,
            maxlength: {
                param: 40,
                depends: function (element) {
                    var valTwo = $('#fieldTwo').val();
                    return !valTwo || (valTwo.length < 8) || (valTwo.length > 18);
                }
            }
        },
        fieldTwo: {
            require_from_group: [1, '.datagroup'],
            minlength: {
                param: 8,
                depends: function (element) {
                    var valOne = $('#fieldOne').val();
                    return !valOne || (valOne.length > 40);
                }
            },
            maxlength: {
                param: 18,
                depends: function (element) {
                    var valOne = $('#fieldOne').val();
                    return !valOne || (valOne.length > 40);
                }
            }
        },
        fieldThree: {
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

Now `fieldOne` and `fieldTwo` are working well together, but I am having issues making `fieldThree` fit in.  It kind of works, but if you only provide a value in `fieldThree` ,although the errors display, the form is still being submitted.

Is there any way to stop this from happening?  I am not sure if this needs to be part of the group?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
<form role="form" id="my_form">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="fieldOne" class="control-label">Field One</label>
     <input type="email" id="fieldOne" class="form-control datagroup" name="fieldOne">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="fieldTwo" class="control-label">Field Two</label>
     <input type="tel" id="fieldTwo" class="form-control datagroup" name="fieldTwo">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="fieldThree" class="control-label">Field Three</label>
     <input id="fieldThree" class="form-control datagroup" name="fieldThree" >
   </div>
   <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="submitButton">Check Information</button>
   <div id="error"></div>
   <div id="results"><span id="spanOne"></span><br><span id="spanTwo"></span></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you add the html as well?

Comment: I have updated to include the HTML, thanks

Comment: You simply need to implement the `require_from_group` method on the first two fields.  This rule is part of the `additional-methods.js` file.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18317702/594235

Comment: I am already using that.  My first two fields are not really a problem.  I just need to make sure that fieldThree is always valid

Comment: If field three is `required`, then it's `required` and has nothing to do with the other two fields.  You seem to be way over-complicating this.  *"although the errors display, the form is still being submitted"* ~ that is impossible with the code you've shown... if the field is required and you've left it empty, you cannot submit the form.